# Issue with C program

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

main(){
    float promAnual=0.0;
    int numMeses, numToneladas,i, suma = 0, mesTon = 0;
    float toneladas[12];

    for(i = 1; i < 13; i++){
        printf("Ingrese la cantidad de toneladas del mes #%d->", i);
        scanf("%f", &toneladas[i] );
     }

    for(i = 1; i < 13; i++){
        suma = suma + toneladas [i];
    }
    promAnual = suma / 12.0;

    for(i = 1; i < 13; i++){
        if(toneladas[i]>promAnual){
            numMeses = numMeses + 1;
        }
    }
    numToneladas = 0;
    mesTon = 0;

    for(i = 1; i < 13; i++){
        if(toneladas[i]>toneladas[i+1]){
            mesTon = i; 
            numToneladas = toneladas[i];
        }
    }

    printf("El promedio anual es: %0.2f, %d mes(es) tuvieron mayor cosecha que el promedio anual, y el mayor numero de toneladas se produjo en el mes #%d con %0.2f", promAnual,numMeses,mesTon, numToneladas);
    }
```

The issue is that the last 2 variables in the last printf are showing wrong values, I know why, but I don't know how to fix it, it is because the last "for" is assigning the last value of "i", but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Is your compiler warning you about anything? Perhaps you should ask a question about *that*, first!

Comment: The question is wrong. It should contain details on a) what is this code supposed to do, b) what is the **expected output**, c) what is the **actual output**. None of this information is in your question.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Improve your (wrong) code to get no warnings. Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of the errors in your code, I'd say you're probably not reading a book to learn. That's unfortunate, because people who read books to learn C usually don't have this kind of trouble.

---

```
float toneladas[12];

for(i = 1; i < 13; i++){
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de toneladas del mes #%d->", i);
    scanf("%f", &toneladas[i] );
 }
```

Here you've declared a carton of 12 eggs, `egg[0]` through to `egg[11]` (write them out and count them one by one, and you'll see there are 12)... and then tried to insert into `egg[12]`, which is out of bounds. Expect one smashed egg!

Throughout that code you're referring to that smashed egg again and again. I wouldn't be surprised if the recipe you're concocting is disastrous!

---

Speaking of smashed eggs, you have an uninitialised variable: `int numMesses` which you then use without initialisation: `numMeses = numMeses + 1;`...

---

```
int numMeses, numToneladas,i, suma = 0, mesTon = 0;
/* SNIP */
printf("El promedio anual es: %0.2f, %d mes(es) tuvieron mayor cosecha que el promedio anual, y el mayor numero de toneladas se produjo en el mes #%d con %0.2f", promAnual,numMeses,mesTon, numToneladas);
```

As you can see, `numToneladas` is declared as `int`. However, in your call to `printf` you're telling `printf` it's a `double`. You're lying to `printf`; no wonder it's lying back at you!

---

You appear to be including the non-portable header `<conio.h>`, though I see no point. Unlike most, you've not used a single function from that header! Why include a non-portable header you're not using?

My only guess is that you're copy/pasting from somewhere, and attempting to learn by unguided trial and error. As you've seen, that's dangerous; it'll cause you headaches due to strange, difficult to debug bugs like the one you've encountered today. You got lucky this time, *because you noticed*. If you write code like this in the real world you might cause someone injury!

**Read a book!** Do the exercises as you stumble across them. I can recommend K&R2E.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but that didn't solved the issue, and no, i'm not copy/pasting from anywhere.

Comment: @Jairo When you write things like that, you should update your question with the fixes to the problems mentioned... edit: *and* tell us what output you expect to see!

Answer (score 0):

you would better check the end condition of "for" loop,  the array toneladas have 12 stores, which from 0 to 11,but you set it from 1 to 12,maybe it cause your issue.
  please try to set "for(i=0;i<12;i++)",and run the code again.